# Connect an app inside docker service container to a database running on external network docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect some app that is a **docker-compose service** to a MongoDB running in a **separate docker container using its own network** on the same host machine. What URL should be used by the app to connect to that external network?

My steps...

Created a network and started MongoDB on that network:

```sh
docker network create my_app_mongo_db
docker run --name db-mongo -d --network=my_app_mongo_db -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

Created a `docker-compose.yaml` like so:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my_app:
    image: my_app
    container_name: my_app
    networks:
      - default
      - my_app_mongo_db
networks:
  default:
  my_app_mongo_db:
    external: true
```

The `docker-compose -up` starts fine and `docker network inspect my_app_mongo_db` shows that the service is connected to the external network.

Next I am trying to connect to MongoDB using this URL, similarly how I would connect to the DB if it was running as a service:

```
mongodb://my_app_mongo_db:27017
```

Yet this approach doesn't work with an external network. What does work is using `host.docker.internal`:

```
mongodb://host.docker.internal:27017
```

But according to [this Docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host):

> This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac.

Any ideas how to resolve this when running on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to connect using the `Container` name not the network , try this:

```
mongodb://db-mongo:27017
```